How are identical rows implied in this proof of the basis minor theorem
I am a computer science and maths graduate and am looking to do some self-study of linear algebra in order to pursue a career change. I am currently reading "linear algebra" by Georgi Shilov and am trying to fully understand a proof of the basis minor theorem in chapter 1. I have attached the relevant excerpt from the book for context. My question is:
"If a value of k is chosen such that k<=r, how does this imply that the matrix has two identical rows?"
Any insight into this specific detail would be greatly appreciated.
Shilovs proof of the basis minor theorem

Previously asked here
